# How to bring the value out of the "exists" query (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I have 2 tables:

```
OrderTable (orderID is unique)
orderID - Date .....
1       - 11/12 ....
2       - 12/12 ....
....

OrderStage (each orderID has many stages)
orderID - Stage
1       - 1
1       - 3
2       - 2
2       - 4
....
```

Now I want to get all order with having max(stage)=3

```
select orderID,... From orderTable where  exists 
(select orderID, MAX(stage) from OrderStage group by orderID Having MAX(stage)=3 )
```

The above query works but i have no idea how to bring the Max stage out of the `OrderStage` table, so that the result will be:

```
orderID - Date ..... - MaxStage
1       - 11/12 .... - 3
```

This is what I tried:

```
select orderID,..., st.maxStage From orderTable where  
exists (select orderID, MAX(stage) maxStage from OrderStage 
group by orderID Having MAX(stage)=3 ) st
```

But MYSQL show errors.

So how to fix this issue.

Note: I can't use JOIN cos I build this query on an existing sql which is very complicated, if i change to JOIN then i could break the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `join` if you want to use the value:

```
select ot.orderID,..., omax.maxStage
From orderTable ot inner join
     (select orderID, MAX(stage) as maxStage
      from OrderStage 
      group by orderID
      Having MAX(stage)=3
     ) omax
     on ot.orderId = omax.orderId;
```

The `inner join` does the filtering and, because of the `group by orderId`, you don't have to worry about rows being inadvertently duplicated in the result set.

Comment: can we not to use JOIN ?

Comment: I remembered I learned in School, they could bring the value out of the exists without using JOIN, but forgot how

Comment: @Tum . . . Then you mislearned SQL.  That is not possible.  The variables in the `select` clause come from the `from` clause.